# My boolean variable could not be resolved into a variable in my while statement

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, do-while

I want to make a code that repeats itself until the user types the word Game or the word Balance. I made a `do while` loop, but I'm getting an error with my while statement. The error is: `error3 cannot be resolved into a variable`. Does anyone know what's the problem with my code?

```java
System.out.println("welcome to Roll the Dice!");
System.out.println("What is your name?");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
String Name = input.nextLine();

System.out.println("Welcome " + Name + "!");
System.out.println("Do you want to play a game or do you want to check your account's balance?");
System.out.println("For the game typ: Game. For you accounts balance typ: Balance");

do {
    String Choice = input.nextLine();
    String Balance = "Balance";
    String Game = "Game";
    input.close();

    boolean error1 = !new String(Choice).equals(Game);
    boolean error2 = !new String(Choice).equals(Balance);
    boolean error3 = (error2 || error1) == true;

    if (new String(Choice).equals(Game)) {
        System.out.println("Start the game!");
    }

    else if (new String(Choice).equals(Balance)) {
        System.out.println("Check the balance");
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("This is not an correct answer");
        System.out.println("Typ: Game to start a game. Typ: Balance to see your account's balance");
    }
}
while ( error3 == true );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error3` is defined inside the `do` scope. Move its declaration outside the `do` scope and set the value inside:

```
    boolean error3 = false;
    do {
        String Choice = input.nextLine();
        String Balance = "Balance";
        String Game = "Game";
        input.close();

        boolean error1 = ! new String(Choice).equals(Game);
        boolean error2 = ! new String(Choice).equals(Balance);
        error3 = error2 || error1;
```

Note also that you can simplify `(error2 || error1) == true` to simply `error2 || error1`. The same can be done for your `while` statement:

```
while(error3);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. But I'm still getting an error i changed my code but he is currently giving me another error. at the line: boolean error3 = error2 || error1; The error is: Link all references for a local rename (does not change references in other files). Do you maybe know a solution for this error aswell? Thanks :)

Comment: Screenshot of the error? Sounds like a refactoring suggestion from an IDE, not a real error.

Comment: Actually, David [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728416/my-boolean-variable-could-not-be-resolved-into-a-variable-in-my-while-statement/54728428#comment96240618_54728426) is correct. `error3 = error2 || error1`, you don't want the `boolean` at the beginning of that line.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read the value of `error3` outside the scope of the loop body where it's declared:

```
while(error3 == true);
```

Simply declare it before the loop:

```
boolean error3 = true;
do {
    //...
    error3 = (error2 || error1) == true; 
    //...
}
while(error3 == true);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. But I'm still getting an error i changed my code but he is currently giving me another error. at the line: boolean error3 = (error2 || error1) == true; The error is: Link all references for a local rename (does not change references in other files). When i run the code Eclipse says: duplicate local variable.  Do you maybe know a solution for this error aswell? Thanks :)

Comment: @StijnKrabbenborg: Because you are trying to re-declare the `error3` variable inside the loop.  Don't re-declare it, use the existing variable like I do in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined the variable inside the do-while loop.
Do this:

```
boolean error3=true;
do {
        String Choice = input.nextLine();
        String Balance = "Balance";
        String Game = "Game";
        input.close();

        boolean error1 = ! new String(Choice).equals(Game);
        boolean error2 = ! new String(Choice).equals(Balance);
        error3 = (error2 || error1) == true; 

        if (new String(Choice).equals(Game)){
            System.out.println("Start the game!");
        }

        else if(new String(Choice).equals(Balance)){
            System.out.println("Check the balance");
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("This is not an correct answer");
            System.out.println("Typ: Game to start a game. Typ: Balance to see your account's balance");
            }
    } 
    while(error3 == true);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. But I'm still getting an error i changed my code but he is currently giving me another error. at the line: boolean error3 = (error2 || error1) == true; The error is: Link all references for a local rename (does not change references in other files). When i run the code Eclipse says: duplicate local variable.  Do you maybe know a solution for this error aswell? Thanks :)

Comment: remove the type boolean from the variable inside the loop

Comment: Accepted answers help others to find the solution quickly.